# Creating text over a div that's marked as position absolute

Tags: css

I'm currently trying to create a website footer which stays positioned at the bottom of the page and have done so, although I'm having a few problems with creating content on top of this div.

```
.footer{
width:100%;
height:80px;
background:#333333;
margin-top:20px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

Above is the current CSS styling options I've used however I still have troubles when try to create divs that display on top of this such as copyright notes.

All help would be gratefully appreciated :)!

Comment: Do you mean position **in** or **on**, because the latter doesn't really exist (or maybe isn't necessary).

Comment: Or do you mean **above** the footer? And is you footer a sticky footer (looks like it from the CSS)?

Answer (score 2):

create a child div like so

```
<div class="footer">

    <div>Copyright Info</div>

</div>
```

And give the child the css `position: relative;` to prevent inheritance of the `position: absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of content you want, but here are a couple examples in a jsFiddle.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qB4Z2/)

Basically, if you want a `<div>` over your footer, put it inside your footer div:

```
<div class ="footer">
 <div class="ele">
  <span class="over">Hello World.</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

And style it giving it dimensions and margins to line it up.

```
.ele {
    margin:auto;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```